# git diff not showing all changes

Tags: git, git-diff

I'm almost embarrassed to ask but when I run `git diff` on a specific file, it only shows the changes on the first 26 lines or so.

Is there a page down command that will show the rest of the changes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `git diff` command by default pipes its output through `less`. Press the space bar. The <kbd>h</kbd> command shows a help screen.

Comment: `pgdn` should cause the screen to scroll down as well.

Comment: Greg, thanks for the quick answer, I'll use this tip every day.